# run a between query using wildcards

Tags: ms-access, vba

Using Microsoft Access 2010

I have a field for [box_no].  I need to run a query to get a list of all box numbers within a range.  Here is my issue....several box numbers have a letter in front of them (typically the letter "T"), several do not.  If I use `*Like* '*'+[Search Box Number]+'*'` in the query I have no problem searching for a box with or without a letter.  I can use `*Between [beginning box number] And [ending box number]*` in the query to retrieve a range of box numbers, as long as I include the corresponding letter(s).  Is there a string or something I can write to get the result I want?

EXAMPLE:  I want to retrieve a report for box numbers 732913000 to 732914000.  732913000 through 73213055 do not have a letter in the beginning.  73213056 has the letter T in the beginning (T73213056).  I need to make sure all box numbers appear in the report, regardless of the beginning character.

I hope this makes sense!  :-)

Comment: Uh, I assume you have asterisks in there somewhere? Can you either surround your example queries with backticks or escape the asterisks with backslashes?

Comment: Can you post your a query you have tried (it's easier to reply with a query if we have a query to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a function in VBA to strip out the leading character if its not numeric and then use that function in your query.

The function would be;

```
Function StripChar(BoxNumber As String) As String

    If IsNumeric(Left(BoxNumber, 1)) Then
        StripChar = BoxNumber
    Else
        StripChar = Right(BoxNumber, Len(BoxNumber) - 1)
    End If

End Function
```

You can then use the function in your query;

```
SELECT BoxNumber, StripChar([BoxNumber]) AS Stripped
FROM <YourTable> WHERE (StripChar([BoxNumber]) Between 100 And 200));
```

You could probably put the whole thing together using SQL but it's probably easier to work with this because you can easily amend the VBA function to do the adaptation.